# localStorage ReactJs not working while push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I just tried to store array data inside localStorage with ReactJs.

Code Below :

```
storeData(){

    const datas = {
        name : this.state.prevName,
        id : Date.now()
    }

   var localDatas = localStorage.getItem('names');

    if(!localDatas){
        localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(datas));
    }else{
        var items = [];
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));
        items.push(datas);
        localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(items));
    }
}
```

It's working first time when undefined localDatas variable. I mean when there is no names set at localStorage. 
if running for first time And whenever i tried to push new data then its generate error. 

Error Below :

> TypeError: items.push is not a function

```
     }else{
     68 |         var items = [];
     69 |         items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));
     > 70 |         items.push(datas);
     71 | ^         localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(items));
     72 |     }
     73 | }
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: You are setting the object value here ```items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'));``` to items so now items is an object and in next line you trying to push object into object which is not valid and hance you are receiving the error as ```items.push is not a function``` ..

Comment: i tried to set object values like this too items=[JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'))] its working but when i push more then 2 datas then its show like [[{name:"a",id:123123},{name:"b",id:22585}]] with index @Maniraj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When first `localDatas` is undefined, it sets the localStorage item as an **object**, not array.

Second time this function is called, items is an object and not an array and therefore no .push for him.

```
        var items = []; // items is array
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names')); // items is now OBJECT!!
        items.push(datas); // can't do a .push to an object
        localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(items));
```

You could just make `datas` an array and everything should work.

```
    const datas = [{
    name : this.state.prevName,
    id : Date.now()
}]
```

**FIX:**
Since datas is now an array and we want to push only the object inside, instead of:
`items.push(datas);` should be: `items.push(datas[0]);`

Comment: It's generate like this 0: {name: "a", id: 1583652932860}
1: [{name: "v", id: 1583652934471}]
2: [{name: "s", id: 1583652936472}]
3: [{name: "adfasf", id: 1583652944449}]

Comment: **Fix:** when you push `datas` to `items`, use this: `items.push(datas[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that JSON.parse is returning an object (not an array). As an object it does not have any "push" method.

You could fix this by making sure "datas" is starting as an array :

```
let storeData = () => {

    const datas = [{
        name : this.state.prevName,
        id : Date.now()
    }]

   var localDatas = localStorage.getItem('names');

    if(!localDatas) {
        localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(datas));
    } else {
        var items = [];
        items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('names'))
        items.push(datas);
        localStorage.setItem('names',JSON.stringify(items));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON.parse function returns an object if the string passed to it represents a JSON object, and an array if the string represents a JSON array. If you're using `window.localStorage.getItem('names')` to retrieve data from local storage and `JSON.parse()` to parse that data, the type of data returned will depend on the string stored in local storage. From your code, you passed on to the local storage, which is the datas.

If you want to ensure that you get an array, you can modify the data stored in local storage to be a JSON string representing an array like this:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify([datas]))
```

In that case

```
data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('data'))
```

will return array for you to perform push and other array functions.